# 403 Forbidden Access While Calling Login Function CodeIgniter 3x

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter-3

I code an application on ubuntu. The application runs well without any problem. But, this problem starts when I decided to run the CI based application locally using XAMPP at Windows.

Front end works without a problem. But, when I tried to login, it gave me "Error 403 Access Forbidden! You don't have permission to access the requested object. It is either read-protected or not readable by server". It seems the application can't call the loginAction function from "System" controller while in my ubuntu client, it worked without 403 forbidden error.

```
http://localhost/myProject/System/loginAction
```

I've tried this thread but it doesn't come with a solution to my case.

[CodeIgniter error 403](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37510478/codeigniter-error-403/37510748)

I've set the project folder's permission to 755 in before (But it doesn't affect the permission really at windows right?)

I also did something to config.php file at these lines :

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/myProject/';
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

My code :

Login view (login.php) :

```php
<form action="<?= base_url(); ?>System/loginAction" method="POST">
      <input type="username" name="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" required maxlength="50" autocomplete="off">
      <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required maxlength="30">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-flat">Sign In</button>
</form>
```

Controller (System.php) :

```
function loginAction() {
     $username = $this->input->post('username');
     $password = $this->input->post('password');

     $where = array(
          'username' => $username,
          'password' => md5($password),
     );

     $cekLogin = $this->Admin_Model->cekLogin('mytb', $where)->num_rows();

     if($cekLogin > 0 && $cekLogin < 2) {

          $dataUser = $this->Admin_Model->getUserData('mytb', $where);

          $dataSession = array(
               //some session data here
          );

          if($dataUser[0]['activeStatus'] == '1') {

          $this->Admin_Model->updateLastLogin($dataUser[0]['idUser']);

          $this->session->set_userdata($dataSession);

          redirect(base_url().'Admin/');

          } else {

               $this->session->set_flashdata('alert_warning', 'This username is in inactive status!');
               redirect(base_url().'Login/');
          }

     } else {

          $this->session->set_flashdata('alert_gagal', 'Wrong username or password!');
          redirect(base_url().'Login/');

     }
}
```

.htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

*Note I haven't touched the .htaccess that is located in the "application" folder.

I'm expecting that the application can do login process through localhost at windows client perfectly as same as localhost at ubuntu client does. I've been stuck at the same problem for hours ;-;

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your controller name. When you browse your url it is pointing to the codeigniter's `system` folder. You may need to change your controller name to fix it.